# Is there any way a captured but non-ceded city can grow again?

Tags: civilization-6

In Civ 6 an opponent has to cede a captured city to you for it to grow again.

Is there any way around this - including with Wonders or Civics or anything else?

I have now wiped out a civilization before he could cede his cities to me - am I now stuck forever with non-growing cities?

On a related note if you decide not to raze a city as soon as you capture it - is there any way to raze it later?

(I can see this leading to ridiculous anti-pattern moves like allowing a city to be captured so you can recapture it again and raze it).

On another related point if a non-ceded city is captured by a third party - do you need to cede it to them or does the original owner? And what if the original owner is dead?

Comment: I'm pretty sure thats not true... I'm almost positive I've captured cities that eventually grow again. The only thing is they tend to be unhappy for a while due to war weariness, but once that passes they are fine.

Comment: Hmm - do you have any idea how long this takes? Have you seen any documentation - would be interesting to know what the criteria is. When this happened had you defeated the civ completely? (perhaps that is a requirement for cities to grow again?).

Comment: The exact length depends on the situation. If you are no longer at war (doesn't matter if you defated the other civ) it goes back up faster.

Comment: Interesting. Hopefully some hard data on these timings will emerge. Having a permanently crippled city wouldn't be good.

Comment: I Captured Spains Capital, its only city. It has been growing since. (The war weariness was there for the start, cant remember how long though)

Comment: I experienced that wiping out a civ automatically cedes all cities. Are you sure the growth-limiting factor is really occupation? (Not housing, for example)

Comment: Now they do appear ceded - perhaps it just takes 1 turn to fix it. If you don't wipe them out what about then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have now wiped out a civilization before he could cede his cities to
>   me - am I now stuck forever with non-growing cities?

When a civilization is completely wiped out it automatically cedes all of their cities.

> On a related note if you decide not to raze a city as soon as you
>   capture it - is there any way to raze it later?

You must raze it immediately otherwise you need to get them to cede before the city will grow in population. As a side note you can force the city to grow with a worker removing resources such as the Jungle if it is close to another population in food.

**NEW GAMEPLAY MECHANICS OR BUG FOR 'RISE AND FALL' EXPANSION**

When making peace with an opponent the city automatically cedes even if you do not choose it in the trade screen. This is a major change, either they intended to remove the ceding system and forgot to remove it from the trading screen or they broke the ceding system.